# Need help adding a column onto subquery table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this table that I have made using this SQL code so far:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM (--Some subtable--) T
```

The problem I have is that I need to some a whole column together. So all I need to do is `SUM(Column_Name)`. I just need that one value with the table T. But when I add that to the `SELECT`, the table T just shows one line with the correct `SUM` totalled up:

```
SELECT T.*, SUM(Column_Name)
FROM (--Some subtable--) T
```

So, all I need is the whole table T and the one `SUM(Column_Name)` together somehow?

How can I merge the sum and table T?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT T.*, SUM(Column_Name) OVER () as total
FROM (--Some subtable--) T
```